# Probability - How to prove that $E(X)=P(T) (E(X) +1)+P(HT)(E(X)+2)+P(HH)(2).$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation

> Suppose that we are given a fair coin and we toss the coin indefinitely. What is the average number of tosses so that two consecutive heads are obtained?

The solution is as follows:

Let $X$ be the random variable denoting the number of tosses required to obtain 2 consecutive heads.

Then we are asked to calculate $E(X) $.

Note that 
$$E(X)=P(T) (E(X) +1)+P(HT)(E(X)+2)+P(HH)(2).$$

Solving the equation leads to

$$E(X) =6.$$

My question is how to prove the equation above.

Comment: Do you know the [Law of iterated expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/law-of-iterated-expectation/)? That's how the equation is obtained.

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate it?I do know the I use of total expectation but no idea how to apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the law of total expectation, the expected value for $X$, the count of tosses until we obtain two heads on consecutive rolls is.$$\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf P(\mathrm T)~\mathsf E(X\mid \mathrm T)+\mathsf P(\mathrm H\mathrm T)~\mathsf E(X\mid \mathrm H\mathrm T)+\mathsf P(\mathrm H\mathrm H)~\mathsf E(X\mid \mathrm H\mathrm H)$$

Where $\mathrm T$ is the event for obtaining a tail on the first roll, $\mathrm H\mathrm T$ is the event for obtaining head then tail on the first two rolls, and $\mathrm H\mathrm H$ is the even for obtaining head on both first two rolls.   These are disjoint events that partition the sample space (ie: they are mutually exclusive and exhaustive events).

Now when we roll a tail on the first roll, we count that roll, then continue as though we have started the experiment over again.  $$\mathsf E(X\mid\mathrm T)=1+\mathsf E(X)$$
Similarly, when we roll a head then a tail we count those rolls then continue as though we have started over.$$\mathsf E(X\mid\mathrm H\mathrm T)=2+\mathsf E(X)$$
However, when we roll two heads, then we are done.$$\mathsf E(X\mid\mathrm{HH})=2$$
Thus$$\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf P(\mathrm T)~(1+\mathsf E(X))+\mathsf P(\mathrm{HT})~(2+\mathsf E(X))+2~\mathsf P(\mathrm {HH})$$

Comment: From my understanding, law of total expectation asserts the equation 
$$E[E(X|Y)] = E(X).$$
In this case, what is your random variable $Y$? I think $X$ denotes the number of tosses to obtain 2 consecutive heads, right?

Comment: Another question: How to prove that $E[X|T] = 1 + E[X]$ rigorously?

Comment: You are conditioning over the sigma algebra generated by the events that partition the outcome space.$$\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid\sigma\{E_i\}))=\sum_i \mathsf P(E_i)~\mathsf E(X\mid E_i)\qquad\text{iff }\{E_i\}\text{ is a partition of the outcome space}$$

Comment: $\mathsf E(X)$ is defined as the expected count of trials in a indefinite sequence of Bernoulli trials until encountering two consecutive successes. $~$ $\mathsf E(X\mid\mathrm T)$ is defined as the expected count of trials in a indefinite sequence of Bernoulli trials until encountering two consecutive successes under the condition that the first trial is not a success. $~$ This equals one plus the expected count of trials in a indefinite sequence of Bernoulli trials until encountering two consecutive successes. $~$ By the definition that is $1+\mathsf E(X)$.

Comment: Is it not possible to prove by definition of conditional expectation with respect to an event? 
$$E[X|T] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty x \cdot P(X=x|T)$$